# Wordpress Custom Post Type Rewrite URLs Dynamically

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called vehicles (vehicle). At present these are working as expected with Manufacturers created without a parent id and Models with the relevant Manufacturer id as the parent id. Looking a bit like this:

```
(1) Audi 
     -> post_parent = 0
     -> post_name = 'audi'

     (2) A4
         -> post_parent = 1
         -> post_name = 'a4'

     (3) A6
         -> post_parent = 1
         -> post_name = 'a6'
```

At present the URLs for these translate to:

```
/audi/ /audi/a4/ /audi/a6/
```

I would like to use a page to prefix these Urls like this:

```
/cars/audi/ /cars/audi/a4/ /cars/audi/a6/
```

Obviously 'cars' is a page and has a different post type (page). I would like to keep the vehicle structure as is because this is easy to manage. I would like to make this as manageable as possible, as in the future I may add a Vans page and so some vehicles may need the 'vans/' prefix later.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don`t recommend "/cars/" as category base if "/cars/" is already the pagetype "page".

How about "/car/" and "/van/"?

Regards Tom

Comment: Are you suggesting that I just create a post type vehicle with the name 'cars'? The idea is that the 'cars' page is a page about the cars, then the cars are appended like so: '/cars/audi/'. '/cars/audi/a4/', etc.

Comment: Yes. And No. And Yes, I'm suggesting that you create a post category named "car" and sort your cars in there with sub-categories, like: "car/audi/a4/". Because your idea conflicts with the page/post model of WordPress.